# How to change a location of *.java files generated by MapStruct?

Tags: java, gradle, mapstruct

I'm using a MapStruct with default configuration. Everything works as expected except build implementation **(*.java)** files location. After application build, they are located at *build/classes/java...* packages with ***.class** files. How to configure MapStruct to avoid such stuff?

I was searching for a similar problem on MapStruct site, but I hadn`t found anything.

```
//build.gradle
dependencies {
    implementation("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:1.2.0.Final")
    annotationProcessor("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:1.2.0.Final")
}
```

Comment: Why is that a problem? These aren't files you want to commit - the whole point is that Mapstruct takes care of generating them whenever the app is run.

Comment: @ChrisNeve, it's not a serious problem, but I have a lot of warnings because of Reflections scanning of these files, like below 

`Caused by: java.io.IOException: bad magic number: xxxxxxxb`. 
I'm not happy with this :(

Comment: Maybe it would be more relevant to configure your IDE to not scan code from the build/ directory ?

Comment: @ChrisNeve, unfortunately, it does not depend on IDE, these warnings appear during the Gradle build task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can configure target directory for generated source files using the annotation processor configuration , for example if you want these files in "/src/generated/java" :

```
compileJava {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.annotationProcessor
    options.setAnnotationProcessorGeneratedSourcesDirectory(file("$projectDir/src/generated/java"))

}
```

**Note** you should not commit these generated files under SCM, so don't forget to update your ".gitignore" file (if you use Git) to exclude `/src/generated/` folder)

Comment: thanks, it works great! But the component model I has left by default.

Comment: Glad it worked. i removed the part with component model, it' not related to your question indeed.